# Powershell script to display all groups and the users they contain

Tags: powershell, scripting, directory

I'm currently trying to write a script that displays each group and user in the domain.

```
        Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Groups = (Get-AdGroup -filter * | Where {$_.name -like "**"} | select name -expandproperty name)

$Table = @()

$Record = [ordered]@{ "Group Name" = ""; "Name" = ""; "Username" = ""; }

Foreach ($Group in $Groups) {

$Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $Group | select name,samaccountname

foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers) { 
$Record.Set_Item("Group Name", $Group) 
$Record.Set_Item("Name", $Member.name) 
$Record.Set_Item("Username", $Member.samaccountname) 
$objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record $Table += $objrecord

}

}

$Table | export-csv "C:\temp\SecurityGroups.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

It always returns these errors:

```
New-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '+='.
At C:\Users\tech\Desktop\list.ps1:17 char:14
+ $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record $Table += $objrecord
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

New-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '+='.
At C:\Users\tech\Desktop\list.ps1:17 char:14
+ $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record $Table += $objrecord
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Repeating over and over.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

BTW This is server 2012 R2

Comment: You've posted this twice now. Please consider removing one of the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue (as the errors state) is this line:

```
$objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record $Table += $objrecord
```

You needed a new line between `$Record` and `$Table`:

```
$objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record
$Table += $objrecord
```

However, you can simplify and remove it. Here's my amended version of your script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Removed "Where" as it filtered nothing; no need for parens; no need to select name before expanding
$Groups = Get-AdGroup -filter * | select -expandproperty name

$Table = @()

foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    $arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $Group | select name,samaccountname

    foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers) { 
        # You can just declare an ordered object inline as a literal rather than pre-declaring.
        $table += [ordered]@{
            "Group Name" = $Group; 
            "Name" = $Member.name; 
            "Username" = $Member.samaccountname 
        }
    }
}

$Table | export-csv "C:\temp\SecurityGroups.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```